# What would be the java equivalent of this Sikuli command?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, sikuli

I'm trying to convert a sikuli script written in Sikuli IDE to Java in eclipse. How can I convert the below line to Java ?

```
type(text_field.png, "sampletext" + `n`)
```

Here is my code

```java
public void Add() {
    Screen s = new Screen();
    try {
        s.click("img/button_Add_Dmp.png", 0);
        s.wait("imgs/text_field.png");
        // I HAVE TO PUT THE TRANSCODED LINE HERE FROM SIKULI IDE

    } catch (FindFailed e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also Please direct me to any tutorial available for this.

Comment: Did you mean that you're trying to convert from Sikuli IDE to Selenium webdriver?  What have you tried and what's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood this question right, in Java it should be:

s.type("text_field.png", "sampletext"+n)

There is a short tutorial here: http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/030-java-dev.html